# Cannot start xampp on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: xampp

When I start xampp with `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` command but it doesn't work.

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.14-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...fail.
XAMPP:  Another FTP daemon is already running.
```

Answer (score 1):

"Another web server is already running." seems to obvious to me. Please "stop" the current one before starting it. So ...

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

or if it supplies it ...

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```